# Отрисовка текстуры в 2D полигоне в XNA/MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь отрисовать 2D фигуру с помощью Vertex и закрасить текстурой. Саму фигуру отрисовываю методом `DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>`. У меня не получается заставить текстуру, наложенную на фигуру, отвечать моими требованиями. Я хочу, что бы эта текстура была статична, без изменения угла и размера но повторялась.

Мне удалось кое что найти в интернете и гайдах и собрать свою версию кода. Текстура ведет себя нормально только когда её размер равен размеру текстуры.

```
public class Vertexic
{
    private VertexPositionTexture[] vertices;
    private VertexPositionTexture[] triangulatedVertices;
    private Vector3 centerPoint;

    private int[] indexes;
    private bool triangulated;

    private int moveIndex;
    private Texture2D texture;

    public Vertexic( )
    {
        texture = Renderer.TextureList[0];

        this.vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[ ]
        {
            new VertexPositionTexture( new Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),   new Vector2( 0, 0 )),
            new VertexPositionTexture( new Vector3( texture.Width, 0, 0 ),  new Vector2( 1, 0 )),
            new VertexPositionTexture( new Vector3( texture.Width, texture.Height, 0 ), new Vector2( 1, 1 )),
            new VertexPositionTexture( new Vector3( 0, texture.Height, 0 ),  new Vector2( 0, 1 )),
        };

        triangulated = false;
        moveIndex = -1;

        triangulatedVertices = new VertexPositionTexture[vertices.Length * 3];
        indexes = new int[vertices.Length];
    }


    public void Triangulate( )
    {
    calculateCenterPoint( );
    setupIndexes( );
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
    {
        setupDrawableTriangle( indexes[i] );
    }

    // texture coord to wrap
    vertices[1].TextureCoordinate.X = GMath.CalcPercentageF( vertices[1].Position.X - vertices[0].Position.X, texture.Width, 1 );
    vertices[2].TextureCoordinate.X = GMath.CalcPercentageF( vertices[2].Position.Y - vertices[1].Position.Y, texture.Height, 1 );
    vertices[3].TextureCoordinate.X = GMath.CalcPercentageF( vertices[3].Position.X - vertices[0].Position.X, texture.Width, 1 );

    triangulated = true;
    //return triangulatedVertices;
    }

    private void calculateCenterPoint( )
    {
    centerPoint = new Vector3( vertices[0].Position.X, vertices[0].Position.Y, 0 );
    }

    private void setupIndexes( )
    {
    for (int i = 1; i < triangulatedVertices.Length; i = i + 3)
    {
        indexes[i / 3] = i - 1;
    }
    }

    private void setupDrawableTriangle( int index )
    {
    triangulatedVertices[index] = vertices[index / 3];
    if (index / 3 != vertices.Length - 1)
        triangulatedVertices[index + 1] = vertices[(index / 3) + 1];
    else
        triangulatedVertices[index + 1] = vertices[0];
    triangulatedVertices[index + 2].Position = centerPoint;
    }

    public void Update( )
    {
        // изменение позиции точек
        if (GInput.Input.MouseIsPressed( true ))
        {
            var mv = GInput.Input.GetMouseVector;

            if (moveIndex == -1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (GInput.Input.GetMouseRectangle.Intersects(
                        new Rectangle( ( int )vertices[i].Position.X, ( int )vertices[i].Position.Y, 8, 8 ) ))
                    {
                        moveIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (moveIndex >= 0)
            {
                vertices[moveIndex].Position.X = mv.X - 4f;
                vertices[moveIndex].Position.Y = mv.Y - 4f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            moveIndex = -1;
        }
    }

    public void Draw( BasicEffect effect )
    {
        if (!triangulated || moveIndex >= 0)
            Triangulate( ); // применяем изменения

        DEGame.GetG.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;

        effect.Texture = texture;
        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply( );

        DEGame.GetG.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(
            PrimitiveType.TriangleList, triangulatedVertices, 0, vertices.Length );

        // points
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            DEGame.sb.Draw( Renderer.Pixel, new Vector2( vertices[i].Position.X, vertices[i].Position.Y ), null,
                moveIndex == i ? Color.White : Color.Gray, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 8, 0, 0f );
        }
    }

}
```

Результат:
[image: результат]

Как сделать текстуру статичной? Что бы она не растягивалась и не изменяла угол? В интернете мало примеров использования Vertex и в них я не нашел ответа.

Comment: PS: Речь идет о 2D графике. Я лишь пытаюсь вывести полигон с наложенным на нем текстурой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы про то, что текстура выглядит нормально, если рисовать квадрат, и неестественно сгибается посередине, если изгибать четырёхугольник?

Проблема в том, что современные видео-карты рисуют треугольники, а не четырёхугольники. В результате, если треугольники получаются разной формы, возникает подобное [искажение](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping):

[image]

В случае, когда надо нарисовать четырёхугольник в перспективе, железо умеет аппаратно корректировать это безобразие. В результате получается искажение как на третьей картинке. Однако при этом четырёхугольник неравномерно растягивается по вертикали.

Можно совершать финты ушами в шейдерах, можно просто добавлять треугольников, пока эффект не уменьшится до терпимого состояния. Для большинства текстур и не слишком сильного искажения это наступает достаточно быстро.

См.:

- [How can I draw a perspective-correct quad](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68021)
- [Quadrilateral Interpolation](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/)
- [Correct glsl affine texture mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12414708)

Comment: Забыл сказать - речь идет о 2D графике. Я лишь пытаюсь вывести полигон с наложенным на нем текстурой. Но я понял о чем вы писали.

Comment: @Eflfe Понятия "2D графика" для современных карт не существует. Вероятно, вы заметили это, когда использовали 3D-векторы для рисования 2D-четырёхугольника. :)

Comment: Да, тут вы правы :D